# Not able to add user from LDAP using wizard, it searches user with no result in 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011-sp1, sdl-tridion

I am facing an issue while adding user in tridion using wizard. It was working before, but now when I enter the domain name, Username in their fields it searches for sometime and gives nothing. There is no error.
Could you please suggest what I need to check. 
Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Shashi Bhan

Comment: Whoah! Sashi - you need to help yourself here. Maybe you can re-write the question so that people have a chance to help you. Firstly - are we talking about LDAP or about Domain users?

Comment: Hi,
I am trying to add User using wizard. Where we Provide Domain name and Username then it searches for users. It is suddenly stopped searching.

Comment: Hope this is giving some clarity about what I am trying to ask?

Comment: So, we should ignore the fact that you mention "from LDAP" in the title of the Question?

Comment: When we enter the domain and username it searches the LDAP directory after that if result comes we add the user in CMS.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was solved by recycling Content manager from running process. Hope this will help others too.

Thanks,
Shashi Bhan

Comment: I had a problem where Directory Service did not show up when adding new user. Restart of the content manager service did the trick.